# ssh-agent and timeout

Tags: git, ssh-agent

I am using a script to update my system:

```
cd /opt/
chmod 600 /opt/updater/.ssh/.pk
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /opt/updater/.ssh/.pk; git stash; git pull origin master'
/opt/updater/bin/updater.sh
```

My problem is that if `/opt/updater/.ssh/.pk` us not readable or the ssh-key was changed, the  process will get stuck like this:

```
  ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /opt/RDE/rdeupdater/.ssh/.pk; git stash; git pull origin master;EX=$?;echo "-$EX" '
/opt/RDE/rdeupdater/.ssh/.pk: No such file or directory
No local changes to save
user@git's password:
```

How can I solve this from getting stuck? Expect isn't allowed on this system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to have `ssh` immediately fail if it tries to do password authentication (thus always only do public/private key authentication).

You could set the environment variable `GIT_SSH` to a shell script to extend the normal `ssh` command to include `-o "PasswordAuthentication no"`, but if you don't normally access the server where the `git`repository is located, you can also set in `~/.ssh_config`:

```
Host server_with_remote_git_repo_name
    PasswordAuthentication no
```

and then override that if you ever need to access `server_with_remote_git_repo_name` with a password, by doing `ssh -o "PasswordAuthentication yes" server_with_remote_git_repo_name`